# Cordova: Cannot find module './android_sdk'

Tags: android, cordova

I checked out a Cordova project from SVN in IntelliJ Webstorm. When I try to run it on an emulated Android device, I receive the error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module './android_sdk'
```

All the other people working on the project can run the project fine. And I can run every project that I have created locally.

Answer (score 1):

in my case (Kubuntu 16.04.2, Ionic 3.3.0, Cordova 7.0.1) i just did this:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

and that did the trick :)